# Error: skelmng failed: Access is denied. (Error code 5) at retrieves attributes for file or directory (Error code 1)

Tags: windows, subdomain, admin, plesk

The above error coming while creating subdomain using windows plesk admin.
I have created sub domains in other domains. But I cant create a sub domain in one domain.
I am getting the following error while creating a sub domain:

> Error: skelmng failed: Access is denied. (Error code 5) at retrieves attributes for file or directory 
>   (Error code 1)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that issue is caused due to insufficient permissions for \Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\ directory. Try to correct it with

"%plesk_cli%\repair.exe" --repair-webspace-security -webspace-name domain.com
"%plesk_cli%\repair.exe" --reconfigure-web-site -web-site-name domain.com